# Induced relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have question on relations:

Let $R \subseteq X \times X$ be any relation on $X$, and define $\sim$ to be the intersection of all equivalence relations in $X \times X$ that contain $R$.

1. Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.
2. Show that $x \sim y$ if and only if at least one of the following conditions is true: $x = y$, or $x R' y$, or there is a finite sequence of elements $z_1, \ldots z_n \in X$ such that $x R' z_1 R' \ldots R' z_n R' y$ where $x R' y$ means "$x R y$ or $y R x$".

I think I understand how to prove all of the above except for proving the "only if" part of 2 above. That is, how can I show that $x \sim y$ implies $x = y$, or $x R' y$, or there is a finite sequence of elements $z_1, \ldots z_n \in X$ such that $x R' z_1 R' \ldots R' z_n R' y$? In particular I am stuck on how to show that a finite sequence of $z$s exists when neither $x=y$ nor $xR'y$ holds.

Thanks for any hints.

Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that the relation $\sim'$ defined in 2. is also an equivalence relation and of course it contains $R$, and any other equivalence relation $E$ that contains $R$ must contain this $\sim'$.

Comment: Sorry what I meant to say was that I was stuck on proving the "only if" part. I always get these confused ... I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Yes. That's for that. Since $\sim'$ (defined by $a=b$ or $\exists z_1,z_2,...: aRz_1Rz_2\dots Rb$) is an equivalence relation which contains $R$, it is included in the intersection, that is, if $a\sim b$ then $a\sim' b$ also holds. -QED-

Comment: Ah I see now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just one clarification, you said that $\sim'$ is included in the intersection $\sim$. Shouldn't it be the other way around? i.e. $\sim'$ includes $\sim$?

Comment: These sentences are equivalent: 1. `$A$ is included in $B$'  2. '$B$ includes $A$'.